# Can not disable ios scroll bouncing in cordova app

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic/cordova in my app. I want to disable ios scroll bouncing. I searched and there was mentioned about `DisallowOverscroll` , but doesn't work. Any idea?

Here is my **config.xml**:

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0"/>
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
```

**NOTE:** I'm using native scroll not ionic js scroll.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? For the longest time I've been using the config.xml to disable scoll bouncing, and now that solution isn't working anymore.